# Removed database out of connection string

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I was given a method to get our database connection string to Sql Server:

```
SqlConnection GetConnectionString()
```

I call that and get what the connection string should be. If the database does not exist, I need the connection string without the database name in it. If I try to use the connection string with the database name in it, I get an error that it cannot connect to the database, which is it since it does not exist.

I am calling like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString().ConnectionString))
```

Is there a way to recreate the connection string easily without the database name?

Comment: you could use a Regular Expression to remove the `initial catalog=xxx;` portion of the connection string.

Comment: @Didaxis Yeah that's what I was thinking. I was hoping there was a way to extract it without having to do it that way.

Comment: If you don't specify the `initial catalog`, then you will be taken to your default database on login.  If that database is not present you will get an error, and the connection will be terminated.  To avoid that, you can connect to `master`, and then check if your DB is available.

Answer (score 13):

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder aBuilder = 
   new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(yourConnectionStringWithDatabase);
aBuilder.InitialCatalog = "";

string yourConnectionStringWithoutDatabase = aBuilder.ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy

```
var connectionString = "data source=someInstance;initial catalog =someDatabase;etc.";

var pattern = "initial catalog[=\\s\\w]+;";

var dbRemoved = Regex.Replace(connectionString, pattern, "");
```

Note that I haven't handled case sensitivity, but this should be a good start for your requirements.